# Nginx and PHP FastCGI php-cgi error: Fatal Error Unable to allocate shared memory segment of 67108864 bytes: mmap: Cannot allocate memory (12)

Tags: php, nginx, debian, virtual-machine

i was trying to set up Nginx with PHP CGI on one of my virtual servers. I tried this by following this tutorial: http://www.farinspace.com/install-and-configure-nginx-server/

Nginx was giving me error 502, so i started examining the error and found php-cgi not starting and just giving the following error:

> root@xxxxx:/home/xxxxx# start-stop-daemon --start --chuid "www-data" --exec /usr/bin/env -- - USER=www-data PATH=/usr/bin PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=1 PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=1 /usr/bin/php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:9000
>
> Sun May 10 03:28:34 2015 (3351): Fatal Error Unable to allocate shared memory segment of 67108864 bytes: mmap: Cannot allocate memory (12)

looking at cat /proc/user_beancounters

```
Version: 2.5
uid  resource                     held              maxheld              barrier                limit              failcnt
78166448:  kmemsize                 14897923             15745024             33554432             41943040                    0
           [...]
           shmpages                     5139                 5139                20480                20480                   28
           [...]
```

it seems that php-cgi is running agianst some memory limit. since my system is using 200MB of 2,2GB RAM i cannot explain or fix this error. I haven't touched the config php.ini, so afaik this limit should be at about 64 MB RAM.
Any suggestions why php-cgi is not working for me?

Answer (score 0):

Failcnt is more than 0 for shmpages, so it looks like php-cgi is bumping up against that limit.

Contact your hosting provider and ask them to increase the shmpages limit would be your best bet.

Comment: I wondered how to interpret the values. due to the fact, that one page has 4kb on my system this results in exactly 80MB. Subtracting the held value this means i have 59 MB left (this seems to be the reason why php cannot allocate the needed default value of 64mb). Unfortunately i have no experience how much php cgi needs to run properly on a some small webprojects plus nagios4